# How to Decode Html in controller

Tags: html, c#-4.0, model-view-controller, html-encode

I have html encoded content which I want to convert into a string:

```
\u003c
meta charset=\&quot;\u0026amp;quot;utf-8\u0026quot;\u0026amp;quot;\&quot; content=\&quot;\u0026amp;quot;\u0026quot;text/html;\u0026amp;quot;\&quot; 
http-equiv=\&quot;\u0026amp;quot;\u0026quot;Content-Type\u0026quot;\u0026amp;quot;\&quot; 
/\u003e\u003cmeta
```

I tried this:

```
string javascriptencode = HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(document.Document);
            string html = HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(javascriptencode);

               string s = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(html);
```

If i want to show this on razor page there is `@html.Raw("");` 
This works, but I want to do this on controller side, how can this be done?

Comment: You need to improve the formatting and make the question more readable. 
Read - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Quoted from there: "Spelling, grammar and punctuation are important! Remember, this is the first part of your question others will see - you want to make a good impression. If you're not comfortable writing in English, ask a friend to proof-read it for you."

Comment: You have an `encoded` string, so you're calling `encode` methods on it?  Have you tried `decoding` ?  `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(document.Document)`  (though you'll probably have to decode with your other steps as well, not just html.